# python 3.5.2 replacing/rewriting dictionary value in txt file from input?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, input, replace

Hello I have issues with replacing numbers and words in txt file. I have dict that is written in txt file like this for example: abc|aaa|bbb|ccc. 
I want to replace last dict value with new one from input and then save it in same txt file without changing first part of dict. like: abc|aaa|bbb|ddd. 
I am getting all same numbers replaced, can't make it to replace specific one.

I forgot the code, sorry.

```
inputQuantity = input("Quantity: ")
f = open("file.txt", "r")
f1 = f.read()
f2 = f1.replace(book["quantity"], inputQuantity)
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(f2)
f.close()
book["quantity"] = inputQuantity
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `abc|aaa|bbb|ccc` and a **`dict`**?

Comment: _"I am getting all same numbers replaced, cant make it to replace specific one."_ Could you, please show what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Are those letters `abcd` actually letters or do they stand for numbers? Is there just one line in that text file? By "last dict value" do you mean whatever is after the last '|' character? I see no dictionary anywhere--it is enough just to replace whatever is after the last `|' character or is something else also involved? You need to clarify your question. You also need to show your attempts so far so we can know just where to help you and you show us that you are not just throwing your homework at us.

Comment: @AGNGaze the code works when i want to replace author of the book, but when i try to replace "1" with input "3", it replaces all "1" with "3" in txt file. Also goes for words, "Yes" or "No" for example.

Comment: @J.DoeDoeJ - and how do you imagine to discern between one `Yes` value from another in your file? Can you actually post an example of your data and what you expect to happen when you try to replace something?

Comment: I doubt this code can run at all and that it is even related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Dict" always seperated with `|` you can use this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().split('|')
'''
now you have a list ['abc','aaa','bbb','ccc']
now can you change 'ccc' like you would change a list
'''
text[3] = 'ddd'
```

If you want to save a "Python dict" `dct = {Key:value}` you can use a module like [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which is part of the standard libary.
Saving and or loading a dict would look like this:

```
import json

dct = {'key':'value'}
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dct, f)

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
print(type(dct))
>>> <class 'dict'>
```